# How to apply auto-filter on export to Excel (xlsx) using JasperSoft Studio 5.61?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using JasperSoft Studio 5.61 to create an excel-formatted spreadsheet. Most of the configuration options are working fine (formulas, content data types) but I cannot get the Auto-Filtering to work properly. I have searched both the community forum and stackoverflow information and cannot get the columns to filter on export to `.xlsx`.

[image]

- **Red Arrow** indicates incorrect position.
- **Blue arrow** is where I marked
  the auto-filter to "Start".
- **Green arrow** is where I marked the    auto-filter to "End"

Comment: Can you pass some relevant jrxml so that we can test it? [mcve].  How are you exporting it in java? or using jasper report server?

Comment: @user2479424 You should use [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter) property. More info [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was confirmed in Jaspersoft Studio v. 5.6.1 and is now fixed. The fix will be part of the upcoming JSS release.